Diamond inscribed in a rectangle
So i want to type this code but i only have written the diamond part.can anyone help me writing the rectangle part
This is the code for the diamond:
a=int(input())
b=a//2
c=b+1

for i in range(0,c):
    for j in range(0,c-i):
        print(" ",end='')

    for l in range(0,i):
        print("*",end='')

    for e in range(0,i-1):
        print("*",end='')

    print()

for i in range(0,c):

     for j in range(0,i):
         print(" ",end='')

     for l in range(0,b-i+1):
         print("*",end='')

     for e in range(0,b-i):  
         print("*",end='')

     print()


The issue is that you need to print both sets of characters at the same time. For example the first line will require a single character (part of the rectangle), then all the spaces and character that make up the diamond, and finally the end character that is part of the rectangle. Try drawing the diagram on paper to visualise what needs to be done.
